# Machine check error while booting from USB

Tags: boot-failure, live-usb

I put the last Ubuntu iso on my USB stick using UNetBootin, after formatting it to fat32. I've already done that before with other operating systems and it worked. I can't actually boot Ubuntu from USB since I get a black screen with the error "Machine check error" on top the an automatic reboot happens. The error appears right after the boot, I can't see anything else before.

I'm using my ASUS K53SV latop. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Check and see if there is a BIOS update for your system.

Comment: I already did, I have the latest BIOS, thanks! And I do remember in the past I was able to run a Live Ubuntu from USB, maybe it was with the previous version.

Comment: How old is the laptop?  Because the error says that there might be a fault in the CPU.

Comment: The laptop is 8 months old and is working fine.

Comment: I have the same laptop and the same problem with LMDE 64-bit. So I guess it's very probable that it's faulty. Have you tried just redoing the USB stick with Unetbootin, or else trying with a different stick? Because I have correctly installed Ubuntu before.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem using the old method, a CD :)

Comment: I have the same problem, except my ASUS zenbook doesn't have a CD drive.  So the accepted answer is a non-answer for my case.

Comment: @wim I see, sorry that's the only solution I found, add your own answer if you find a better one, I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: The solution which worked for me was toggling the UEFI setting in BIOS.  The problem is related to "secure boot" feature.

Comment: Cool, can't try to do the same as I don't have that laptop anymore...but thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a workaround than a solution, but since I couldn't solve the problem with the USB stick, I was finally able to boot from a CD, that's how I installed Ubuntu on my Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is completely related to the Bios settings. 
Try:

First of all, double check that the .iso image you downloaded is sane. In order to do that you can [check the MD5SUM signature](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) to completely discard that your iso is corrupted due to an incomplete download. (I know it is a silly thing, but it was actually my first error, the image was corrupted. If that's your case too, download it again).

1) Disable the "secure boot" feature in your bios

*-Reboot, select the boot unit (that should say something starting with UEFI if you are booting from a USB Stick) and try to boot. If that does not work, try the next step.*

2) if you have an intel processor, then try disabling the "Vitualization Technology" feature

*-Reboot, select the boot unit (that should say something starting with UEFI) and try to boot. That worked for me. *

notes: for sure you will need to disable the first. Try it alone, then try it combined with the Virtualization Technology disabled. If it works, like in my case, you can turn it on again cause it affects the performance of the virtual machines you may use (e.g. with VMWARE or Virtualbox). If you don't know what a virtual machine is, then you can leave the VT off.

*Tested in an Asus Zenbook from 2014.*

Cheers!