# Machine check error when booting from USB

Tags: boot, usb, 13.10

I am trying to install 13.10.  I have created a startup USB with the built-in startup disk creator and I have also tried using unetbootin, both give me this error on boot-up, just a black screen with the message "Machine check error".

I am using an ASUS zenbook UX31.  It is working fine otherwise, and I have boot from USB without problems with other versions of Ubuntu several times before.  I have seen this [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157160/machine-check-error-while-booting-from-usb) but the accepted answer there is a workaround, not a solution - I can not boot from CD because I am using an ultrabook without any CD drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to "secure boot" feature.  The fix is toggling the UEFI setting in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Toshiba Satellite p850, "Machine check error".

After disabling "Virtualization Technology" in BIOS I could boot from USB stick without problems.

Edit: On further investigation, it seems to require toggling rather than disabling. Tested with Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu Studio 13.10.

Comment: Indeed, toggling the "Virtualization Technology" also worked in my asus zenbook. By the way, you also need to disable the "secure boot" feature, otherwise it won't work. Cheers!